# Azure DevOps Publish to the App Store TestFlight track fails with exit code 1

Tags: azure, app-store, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are trying to publish the IPA to App Store. but task is getting failed with error code 1.

2021-12-22T13:40:44.9828920Z ##[section]Starting: Publish to the App Store TestFlight track
2021-12-22T13:40:44.9841780Z ==============================================================================
2021-12-22T13:40:44.9842160Z Task : Apple App Store Release
2021-12-22T13:40:44.9842730Z Description : Release an app to TestFlight or the Apple App Store
2021-12-22T13:40:44.9843080Z Version : 1.189.0
2021-12-22T13:40:44.9843340Z Author : Microsoft Corporation
2021-12-22T13:40:44.9843860Z Help : More Information
2021-12-22T13:40:44.9844350Z ==============================================================================
2021-12-22T13:40:45.2032820Z [command]/usr/local/opt/ruby@2.7/bin/gem install fastlane
2021-12-22T13:41:12.7283020Z Successfully installed fastlane-2.199.0
2021-12-22T13:41:12.7285250Z Parsing documentation for fastlane-2.199.0
2021-12-22T13:41:12.7287270Z Installing ri documentation for fastlane-2.199.0
2021-12-22T13:41:12.7288910Z Done installing documentation for fastlane after 23 seconds
2021-12-22T13:41:12.7290200Z 1 gem installed
2021-12-22T13:41:12.7637580Z [command]/usr/local/opt/ruby@2.7/bin/gem update fastlane -i /Users/runner/.gem-cache
2021-12-22T13:41:15.6010280Z Updating installed gems
2021-12-22T13:41:15.6010960Z Nothing to update
2021-12-22T13:41:15.6330030Z [command]/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/fastlane pilot upload --api_key_path /Users/runner/work/_temp/api_key***.json -i /Users/runner/work/r1/a/_Calendar-Mobile-Build/Calendar-MobileApp/ExtractedFiles/in.store.calendar.ipa -a in.store.calendar --skip_submission true --skip_waiting_for_build_processing true -p 1596887926
2021-12-22T13:41:18.3757000Z [13:41:18]: �[33mGet started using a Gemfile for fastlane https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#use-a-gemfile�[0m
2021-12-22T13:41:24.9984700Z [13:41:24]: Sending anonymous analytics information
2021-12-22T13:41:25.0084340Z [13:41:24]: Learn more at https://docs.fastlane.tools/#metrics
2021-12-22T13:41:25.0085930Z [13:41:24]: No personal or sensitive data is sent.
2021-12-22T13:41:25.0087420Z [13:41:24]: You can disable this by adding opt_out_usage at the top of your Fastfile
2021-12-22T13:41:25.0342540Z
2021-12-22T13:41:25.0347110Z Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...
2021-12-22T13:41:25.0347960Z
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5644610Z ➡️ Pilot fails using environment variables on GitHub
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5646070Z https://github.com//issues/18655 [open] 11 
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5646810Z 2 weeks ago
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5647060Z
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5681000Z ➡️ Pilot and deliver fails with "string contains null byte"
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5682210Z https://github.com//issues/18312 [closed] 7 
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5685140Z 12 Jul 2021
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5685600Z
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5687110Z ➡️ Deliver step gets stuck while running Transporter
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5688670Z https://github.com//issues/19428 [closed] 0 
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5689470Z 2 weeks ago
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5689810Z
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5690920Z and 8 more at: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/search?q=string%20contains%20null%20byte&type=Issues&utf8=✓
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5691290Z
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5692440Z  You can ⌘ + double-click on links to open them directly in your browser.
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5693940Z /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/token.rb:71:in initialize': [!] string contains null byte (ArgumentError) 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5695490Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/token.rb:71:in new'
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5696930Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/token.rb:71:in create' 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5698560Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/token.rb:49:in from_json_file'
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5700740Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/token.rb:33:in from' 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5702140Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/pilot/lib/pilot/manager.rb:23:in login'
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5703520Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/pilot/lib/pilot/manager.rb:19:in start' 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5704920Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/pilot/lib/pilot/build_manager.rb:17:in upload'
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5706370Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/pilot/lib/pilot/commands_generator.rb:67:in block (2 levels) in run' 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5707770Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:187:in call'
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5709110Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:157:in run' 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5710430Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/runner.rb:444:in run_active_command'
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5711890Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:117:in run!' 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5713720Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/delegates.rb:18:in run!'
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5715210Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/pilot/lib/pilot/commands_generator.rb:167:in run' 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5716630Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/pilot/lib/pilot/commands_generator.rb:19:in start'
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5718090Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:114:in take_off' 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5719490Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/bin/fastlane:23:in <top (required)>'
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5720740Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/fastlane:25:in load' 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5721910Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/fastlane:25:in

'
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5723370Z /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/token.rb:71:in initialize': string contains null byte (ArgumentError) 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5724890Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/token.rb:71:in new'
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5727030Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/token.rb:71:in create' 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5728480Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/token.rb:49:in from_json_file'
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5729920Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/token.rb:33:in from' 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5731260Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/pilot/lib/pilot/manager.rb:23:in login'
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5732610Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/pilot/lib/pilot/manager.rb:19:in start' 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5734180Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/pilot/lib/pilot/build_manager.rb:17:in upload'
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5735680Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/pilot/lib/pilot/commands_generator.rb:67:in block (2 levels) in run' 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5737030Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:187:in call'
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5738370Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:157:in run' 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5739750Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/runner.rb:444:in run_active_command'
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5741190Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:117:in run!' 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5742590Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/delegates.rb:18:in run!'
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5744360Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/pilot/lib/pilot/commands_generator.rb:167:in run' 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5745800Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/pilot/lib/pilot/commands_generator.rb:19:in start'
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5747260Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:114:in take_off' 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5748660Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/bin/fastlane:23:in <top (required)>'
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5749910Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/fastlane:25:in load' 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5751100Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/fastlane:25:in '
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5788050Z ##[error]Error: The process '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/fastlane' failed with exit code 1
2021-12-22T13:41:25.5806900Z ##[section]Finishing: Publish to the App Store TestFlight track

Answer (score 3):

(nice if you could space the output.. :)

I was experiencing this issue in my pipeline. The culprit is

`2021-12-22T13:41:25.5723370Z /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/token.rb:71:in initialize': string contains null byte (ArgumentError) 2021-12-22T13:41:25.5724890Z from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.199.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/token.rb:71:in new'`

Fastlane requires the .p8 key file in your service connection to be base64 encoded to use in the **AppStoreRelease@1** task.

The issue is described here: https://github.com/microsoft/app-store-vsts-extension/issues/219

Try updating your service connection Key Content with a base64 encoded key. You can use the tool https://www.base64encode.org/ to complete online

[image]

Comment: This was it! They want the Base64 of the entire contents of the file.